# What is this symbol in my XMLSpy schema view diagram?

Tags: xmlspy

[image: WTFisthis]

Can someone please tell me what the blue highlighted icon between the spec nodes represents?  I converted this schema into c# classes and I am unable to get to SpecItem, SpecGroup or SpecMisc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this web site:

http://www.diversitycampus.net/projects/tdwg-sdd/minutes/SchemaDocu/SchemaDesignElements.html

**EDIT**

The old link is no longer working, however, I'm keeping it for reference. The new link is as follows:

http://manual.altova.com/xmlspy/spyenterprise/index.html?xseditingviews_schv_cmview_objects.htm

About 1/2 of the way down, you will see the following description:

> A choice of elements. Only a single element from those in the choice
>   may appear at this position.

Comment: The link provided by Jason Heine is no longer working. You can get the information from the [Altova reference guide 2016 edition](http://manual.altova.com/xmlspy/spyenterprise/index.html?xseditingviews_schv_cmview_objects.htm)

Comment: @EduardoBallesteros I've updated my answer to include the new link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That element was selected when you captured the screen or saved the diagram, that's all.  As a practice I always select the left most object to avoid this issue in my documentation.